# Change name of remote BLE device in android programmatically

Tags: android, device, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to know, is it possible to change name of remote BLE device prograamically in android. I am new in BLE app developement. Please help if someone have any idea about this.

Comment: did you get any answer yet???